# Extracting digits in line and storing them to list in Python

Tags: python, split, extract

I have a text file which produces the string " Created Form XX," where XX is an integer. I would like to extract only the integer and save that to a list to be used later in my python program.

Below is code for what I have been able to do so far but am not able to display the digits

```
import re
with open("filename.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    if "form" in line:
      re.findall('\d+', line)
```

How do I print the output of the last line of code and assign to a list?

Comment: What does ```re.findall``` return?

Comment: has your line always the same format ? " Created Form XX" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of matched values (in your case list of numbers that got matched). You should assign the list back to a variable (so that you can use it later on) -

```
nums = re.findall('\d+', line)
```

If you want to print this list, you can simply do -

```
print(nums)
```

For if you want to print each matched element in a separate line , you can use a `for` loop or [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) -

```
for i in nums:
    print(i)
```

You can keep a list at the top, that stores all the numbers you found the file, and extend that list with the `nums` list. Example -

```
import re
numslist = []
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "form" in line:
            nums = re.findall('\d+', line)
            numslist.extend(nums)
```